# Religious Symbols in Naruto

Tags: naruto

[image]

Why are there religious symbols in the design of *Mangekyou Sharingan*?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking... could you please clearify your question, for example adding a picture of the title where you mark the symbols you think symbolize the illuminati. And what do you mean by ``behind making``?

Comment: i mean@Armin ,why there are few symbols visible illuminati?

Comment: before that i'm sorry about my question , cause i'm biginner to use a english language . @Armin

Comment: i am not sure how the Star of David and the number 6 fit at all with the illuminati considering that when i google their logo i get The Eye of Providence or the eye ontop of a pyramid and to my knowledge there was never hexagon-base pyramids, only square-base pyramids which has 4 sides. also in the left image it's inconsistent. one of the sixes is fat while the other 2 are tall? and 2 of the sixes only overlap once?

Comment: @Memor-X i tried editing the question so it makes a little bit more sense... hopefully xD

Answer (score 4):

The association of these images towards some religious symbols or to the Illuminati are a clear sign of over interpretation. Your issue is primarily with the *Mangekyou Sharingan*.

The left picture is Itachi's Mangekyou Sharingan. It depicts a [pinwheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinwheel_(toy)) with three curls. Here is an image of one with four curls, but the 2D representation would be roughly the same.

[image: Pinwheel with 4 curls]

When I read Naruto in the past, I thought it was a *Shuriken*.

[image: A Shuriken]

The second one is Sasuke's Mangekyou Sharingan. According to [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangekyou_Sharingan#Overview), it also resembles a pinwheel, only with six curls.

But the first thing I saw when I looked at it was a model of an atom.

[image: An Atom]

It could also be a six-petaled lotus blossom.

[image: six-petaled lotus]

According to [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangekyou_Sharingan#Overview), all *Mangekyou Sharingan* resemble pinwheels. So no religious symbols and no Illuminati at all.